# LOVE2D mapping pixel error

Tags: lua, love2d

So when I try and map this rgb value onto my data:

```
image=love.image.newImageData(WIDTH,HEIGHT,"rgba16f")

image:mapPixel(pixelFunction)

image2=love.graphics.newImage(image)


function pixelFunction(x, y, r, g, b, a)
    return 0,50,0,255
end
```

I get this[image]

As you can see this is something like (0,255,0,255) not the rgb value I wanted, in fact it seems only able to render the max red green or blue value, making the function ponitless

Answer (score 0):

As one could guess from the fact that only extreme colors are generated, the value `50` is beyond the dynamic range. Using rgba representation in fractions of one (0, 50/255, 0, 1) does result in dark green.

(0,50,0,255) used to work in love 10. According to [wiki](https://love2d.org/wiki/PixelFormat) it should work in love 11 with "rgba16f" that you seem to set. But it doesn't. Proceed to their bug reports section.

Also, please note that [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the question should have been done along these lines:

```
WIDTH=300; HEIGHT=300;
imageData=love.image.newImageData(WIDTH,HEIGHT,'rgba16f')

function pixelFunction(x, y, r, g, b, a)
    return 0,50/255,0,255
end

imageData:mapPixel(pixelFunction)

image=love.graphics.newImage(imageData)

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.draw(image,0,0)
end
```

And yes, you've botched the order of definition and usage.